# json date format in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot and I have an entity class defined something like this

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime start_date;
...
...
}
```

When this class is converted to JSON, the field gets converted to the following string representation

```
{"start_date":[2014,11,15,0,0,0,0],...., ...}
```

I want to have the json response as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I tried the `@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)` annotation and that did not help either.

Is there an easy way to do this conversion to proper json format ?

Comment: `objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are three things that you need to do to format the date as `yyyy-MM-dd`:

1. Add a dependency on `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda`. Judging by the output you're getting at the moment, I think you may already have this dependency.
2. Configure Jackson not to format dates as timestamps by adding `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps: false` to your `application.properties` file.
3. Annotate the `LocalDataTime` field or getter method with `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")`

**Note:** You'll need to use Spring Boot 1.2 for step 2 to work.

Comment: Thank you. I had to upgrade to spring 1.2 and then added the property in the application.yaml file and it worked for me. No @JsonFormat annotation was needed

Comment: Which property did you have to add in application.yaml to change the date format?

Comment: Step 3 appears to be unnecessary (that is the default format). AND actually appears to be ineffectual if you try any other formats.  I'm still investigating but it doesn't seem to be even looking at the JsonFormat annotation

Answer (score 10):

**Without additional dependency** - the only thing I had to do is:

1. To take care send date from client **as string object**, in format `yyyy/MM/dd`
2. In Spring Boot application, to add annotation on the date field with
   the same format

---

```
public class Foo
{
     @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd")
     private Date dueDate;
}
```

*Using Spring Boot 2.3.5 version*

---

#### Update

**Another** option, instead of step 2, to modify application.properties file, add there the format for any Date object:

spring.jackson.date-format=**yyyy/MM/dd**

Answer (score 2):

You can use @JsonFormat annotation in and the desired pattern like this without using any dependency :

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date created_At;
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time struggling with Spring Boot Application + Date Format for my input so I'll try to resume what I saw.

1. If your date is argument to a function, you can use `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` to define a pattern (ie. `org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat`).
2. If your date is inside an object argument to the function, you can use @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") to define a pattern (ie. `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat`)
3. If neither of these works, you can try changing your date Type, for me I had tu use `org.joda.time.LocalDate` in order to make it work with option 2 :

```java
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private org.joda.time.LocalDate date;
```