# Spring Boot - return dates (not as timestamps)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring-Boot 1.2.2 with this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dates", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Date getDates() {
    return new Date();
}
```

which returns this response:

```
1433241315047
```

How can I make it return `"Sun May 31 16:26:43 IDT 2015"` ?
I found some examples on Google like `mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)` but can't figure out where should I write this...

**UPDATE:**
I added 2 dependencies to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and added `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd` to `application.properties`
and still getting timestamps, so I started to eliminate all unnecessary code and found that removing the `@Configuration` annotation from my `WebConfiguration.java` solve the this issue:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>     httpMessageConverters) {

        httpMessageConverters.add(new     MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

I guess this class somehow override date-format setting... So can I specify the date-format here?

Comment: Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @EricMartinez I can't... later I will need to apply this to a third-party component which uses `Date`

Comment: Hi Shoham, would you please remove the solution from the question and add it to the answer section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the dependency Add a dependency on com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda and add spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps: false to your application.properties file.

Here is a similar post - [json date format in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516499/json-date-format-in-spring-boot)

In your application.properties add
spring.jackson.date-format= # Date format string (e.g. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), or a fully-qualified date format class name (e.g. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat)

You could try writing a custom date deserializer -

//CustomDateSerializer class

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {   
}
```

However, in this case you would need to annotate the getter method of date @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter    customJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
   MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new           MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
  jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
  return jsonConverter;
 }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>   converters) {
  converters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
 super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters();
}
  }
```

Comment: I added `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>` to my pom and `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps = false` to my application.properties but its still returns timestamps

Comment: also tried to add `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")` after @RequestMapping but its the same

Comment: @shoham can you try In your application.properties add
spring.jackson.date-format= # Date format string (e.g. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), or a fully-qualified date format class name (e.g. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat)

Comment: I added `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd`  to application.properties but no luck

Comment: @shoham all the research i did points that this shuld work. There is another method we could try out..try writing a custom date deserializer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038005/spring-3-1-json-date-format

Comment: I would use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` instead

Answer (score 5):

`spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd` in `application.properties` works