# Jackson change timestamp format

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm outputting some database results via `json` webservice. Simple as:

```
@GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
public List<Map<String, Object>> get(Param params) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, params)
}
```

Problem: `java.sql.Timestamp` is converted to format `2018-04-26T07:52:02.000+0000`, while the plain database output would be `2018-04-26 07:52:02.0`.

Question: is there any configuration property to tell spring to just pass through the native timestamp received from the database, instead of converting it with `jackson` logic?

I want to change the `java.sql.Timestamp` format **globally**.

**Important**: please don't suggest any annotations! I don't have any bean/pojo, I'm just returning the plain database result as a `Map`.

Comment: Did you already try the `@JsonFormat` annotation?  http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat

Comment: Possible Duplicate of :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516499/json-date-format-in-spring-boot

Comment: As written, I'm not creating a bean. I don't have explicit fields defined where I could add an annotation. I'm just returning the database rows directly from the query result. No pojo/dto involved.

Comment: @narayan-sambireddy clearly NOT a duplicate, because there an annotation is suggested. As written, I cannot make use of annotations here!

Comment: Could you please update the question, the snippet seems to return from a void method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to change the `java.sql.Timestamp` format **globally**.

Set a date format to your `ObjectMapper` instance:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"));
```

In Spring applications, you can expose the `ObjectMapper` instance as a bean:

```java
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"));
    return mapper;
}
```

In Spring Boot you can use the property `spring.jackson.date-format` to define the date format:

```
spring.jackson.date-format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S
```

For more details on the common application properties, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

---

Consider the following code:

```java
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("date", new Timestamp(ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant().toEpochMilli()));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(data));
```

It will print:

```json
{"date":"2018-04-26 07:25:14.408"}
```

Comment: `spring.jackson.date-format` property fits perfectly without having to add any code.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you need this as a Spring @Bean

```
    @Bean
    public JacksonProperties jacksonProperties() {
        JacksonProperties properties = new JacksonProperties();
        properties.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); // put any pattern you need
        return properties;
    }
```