# How properly configure Date serialization in spring mvc controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my spring boot app I have controller method, in kotlin:

```
@GetMapping("/testDate")
@ResponseBody
fun testDate(): ResponseEntity<Date> {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(Date())
}
```

Date - it is java.util.Date.

This method response is timestamp. For example, `1572869050518`. I want to use custom format anywhere in my app, for example 'dd.MM.yyyy'. And I cannot find a way how to configure it.

I use classes with `Date` fields from other app, and API of other app to get it. So, I can't annotate fields with @JsonFormat or other annotations. I get ready objects and return it in controllers to show it to users.

I read [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates), then add `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` - no effect in result.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516499/json-date-format-in-spring-boot) SO questions I found that `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda` must be added. Ok, I add it, no effect in result.

I add `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false`, no effect.

And last, I found §3.6 in [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#format-configuring-formatting-globaldatetimeformat), add configuration with `FormattingConversionService` bean like in example, no effect.

Is there working example how to configure default date formatting in spring mvc app?

*UPD1.* Does not matter is date a part of another object. If I introduce class `data class TestDateObj(var dt: Date)`, change method to

```
@GetMapping("/testDate")
@ResponseBody
fun testDate(): ResponseEntity<TestDateObj> {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(TestDateObj(dt = Date()))
}
```

I get `{"dt":1572878129672}` in result.

Comment: All those configurations only apply when the `Date` is part of on object. Here your body is the date and then those don't apply.

Comment: Please see UPD1

Comment: @AlexT, which version of spring boot do you use?

Comment: I use 2.1.7.Release

Comment: Which `Date` object you are serializing? So the FQN of `Date`?

Comment: Date - it is java.util.Date.

Comment: Now I switch to spring boot 2.2.0. Nothing changes.